# decompile Windows Perl App

Tags: perl, decompiling

I want to protect my Perl Apps.

Is it possible to decompile an executable file which was compiled under Windows?

If yes, how (which Tools can be used)?

And how can I prevent such decompiling?

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=264654

Comment: Ought to work for v5.8, http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PAR-Packer-1.003/lib/PAR/Filter/Bytecode.pm

Comment: Thanks! Are there some decompiling tools for testing my executeable files?

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking, you can't. Perl is an interpreted language, which means the interpreter has to be able to understand your code.
And even if that were not so, your processor has to be able to understand it to run it.

It is therefore functionally impossible to protect your code - at least at the same time as actually being able to run it. A lot of companies have spent a lot of money trying to do this - it's called digital rights management, and even then they've met with limited success, and only really managed it by restricting every device involved. This isn't viable on a computer system for general purpose use.

So short answer - no, you can't do this. Don't even bother trying. If you're worried about someone seeing/using your code... don't release it. Or do so under license agreements that prevent doing so. (That still won't stop them, but it might give you some manner of legal redress).

But there is no technical solution to this "problem" - you cannot simultaneously give someone access and not give them access. Consider what you are trying to accomplish and decide if it's really worth it. If it is that important, you may need to come up with alternative solutions (like, for example, hosting a service which allows users to submit data and get a result)

Comment: Are there some tools available that I can test it on my compiled (packaged) perl scripts?